# Reading an input file n x n grid and reading empty space

Tags: java

I am trying to read an input file for something for an n x n fifteen sliding puzzle solver. The actual solving is not important right now because I can't even get through the input file reading part.

A number of board input files will be sent in and they look like this:

```
3
 5  1  2
 8     3
 4  6  7
```

the top number is n (n x n grid). The input files cannot be changed so I can't make my life easier by representing the space with a 0 and then reading normally. I want to be able to read it into the code as a 2d array like so:

```
5 1 2
8 0 3
4 6 7
```

(0 representing the empty space at (1, 1) in the code)

The exact number of spaces between the numbers are also kind of weird in the input files because sometimes it's 2 spaces and sometimes it's 1 space (e.g. here's another larger input file):

```
9
38 51 15 17 11 27  8 36  7
19 40 28 10 14  4 77 26  9
43  2  5 18 71 22 20 32 13
37 34 76  6 48 25 35 44 53
 1 56 65 39 70 24 62 79 42
30 74 68    58 55 45 60 33
67 29 75  3 41 59 73 63 80
47 12 31 49 50 61 57 72 16
66 23 64 21 78 54 69 52 46
```

I tried this:

```java
File input = new File(args[0]);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

int n = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine();
int[][] board = new int[n][n];
int emptyRow = -1;
int emptyCol = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            board[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
        } else {
            // Empty space
            board[i][j] = 0;
            emptyRow = i;
            emptyCol = j;
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs this for the example 3x3 above:

```
5 1 2 
8 3 4
6 7 0
```

So, it doesn't even know at what position the empty space is; I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: You have proposed two 3x3 examples : `3 5 1 2 8 3 4 6 7` and `3 5 1 2 8 0 3 4 6 7`. The output is ok with the first example. What did you expect ?

Comment: @strugglingnewb I had to edit your question because it was utterly unreadable before. You should read your own question back after posting it to check it looks readable.

Comment: sorry it's my first time posting i'll try to make future posts a little less cluttered

that's not what it actually outputs that's what i want it to output and i'm asking how i could get it to do that

Comment: What is the maximal size of the grid? Could there be 3 digit numbers or not?

Comment: no 3 digit numbers; maximum that the test cases go up to are 9x9 grids, so that's what I'll assume is the max I need to account for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your examples. The idea is to process each line separately, find all numbers in it.

If there are not enough numbers, then a line contains an empty cell. In this case we should find the location of it and skip it.

```java
public static int[][] main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File input = new File(args[0]);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    int[][] board = new int[n][n];
    int currentRow = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        var digits = Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
                .filter(d -> !Objects.equals(d, ""))
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        int emptyCellIndex = -1;
        // found empty cell
        if (digits.size() != n) {
            emptyCellIndex = (line.indexOf("   ") + 2) / 3;
        }
        int iter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i == emptyCellIndex) {
                continue;
            }
            board[currentRow][i] = digits.get(iter);
            iter++;
        }
        currentRow++;
    }
    return board;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If fixed number (spaceNum) spaces split each row of the input data, you can read each line n times and divide each line by the spaceNum spaces.

Here is a sample:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int[] row = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" {"+spaceNum+"}")).mapToInt(s -> {
        try{
            return Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            return 0;
        }
    }).toArray();

    board[i] = row;
}
```

Comment: I would rather go with ```if( s.trim().isEmpty() ) { return ... }``` than exception

Comment: @MBobrik Yes it would be better in this question,  but using try-catch is more general.

Comment: Provided that this generality is desired. Even then, I would rather have a separate *if* path for the valid non-nummerical value(s) and the try/catch for altogether invalid inputs